# Using else before a noun

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I wonder if I can say this:

What **else the option** have I got?

Does it sound natural and applicable in a conversation?

What I've seen or heard so far about the word 'else' are something else, anything else, somebody else, etc. I've never seen else+noun.

Comment: "other" would be the choice here. "What other option have I got?" or "What other option do I have?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't grammatical (in any variety of English as far as I know).

*Else* modifies an indefinite pronoun or adverb (*anything*, *somewhere* etc), and the result is syntactically the same as the unmodified word; so you can use *somewhere else* where you could use *somewhere* etc.

You can't normally use these indefinites to premodify a noun (**an anywhere person*) so you can't use them with *else* to premodify a noun.

These words are occasionally used adjectivally in a playful or poetic way ("A somewhere man"), and in that construction you could use *else* ("he's a somewhere else man") but it is not idiomatic.